# How to Include Snippet from App in Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app

**What I am trying to do:**

- I am trying to create an app that inserts content to the merchant's product page.
- It appears that an app extension into the merchant's Online Store is the most effective way to do this (see https://shopify.dev/docs/app-extensions/extension-areas#online-store/).
- In order to display the content, I am trying to use either a snippet or a section. However, I cannot get either of them to work properly.

**I have taken these steps for the snippet:**

- I have enabled Online store as an extension area within my app (see https://shopify.dev/tutorials/add-a-new-app-extension)
- With the Online store extension enabled, I have created a new snippet and a new section with very basic liquid code `<h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>`
- I have enabled my app into a test store on my Shopify Partner account
- I have added the `{% render 'shopify://apps/etc... %}` code into the correct position within the product page

**Problem:**

- The content is not rendered
- I have even tried this with the Sections Compatible version of the Debut template (see https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-get-started-with-online-store-design-experience). Still nothing.

Is someone able to point me in the right direction here?

Comment: How did you create your snippet? Did you add it to the remote theme you are working with? FYI snippets and sections are local to each theme and won't be globally available to each theme. [This](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/asset?api[version]=2020-04) might help. Good luck!